# How to upgrade libgnutls30 from 3.5.18 to 3.6.6 through dpkg or other ways

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I want to `sudo apt-get upgrade`
But it says that

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    apt : Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.6.5) but 3.5.18-1ubuntu1 is installed

However, I actually just have run `sudo dpkg -i libgnutls30_3.6.6-2_amd64.deb` previously.

(At that time, the terminal returned:

> - dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'libgnutls30_3.6.6-2_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end
>     of file or stream
> - dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input
> - **cannot copy archive member from 'libgnutls30_3.6.6-2_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream**

)

If I execute `dpkg -l libgnutls30`, the detailed information says that the version is **3.5.18**.

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From other forums, I found the solution.
The root cause is that **the download is corrupted**.
So I re download again, namely, I execute

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnutls28/libgnutls30_3.6.6-2_amd64.deb
```

again.

The system automatically named it libgnutls30_3.6.6-2_amd64.deb.2

And then we can run `dpkg -i libgnutls30_3.6.6-2_amd64.deb.2`